# pandas groupby column values and replace grouped values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

| Ticker | instrument_name | year | month | instrument_type | expiry_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABAN10SEPFUT | ABAN | 10 | SEP | FUT | NaN |
| ABAN10OCTFUT | ABAN | 10 | OCT | FUT | NaN |
| ABAN10NOVFUT | ABAN | 10 | NOV | FUT | NaN |

I want to groupby **instrument_type** ('FUT') & find unique values in **month**.
Then compare unique values with **month** column and replace values with 'I','II','III' in the **expiry_type** column.

Result expected:

| Ticker | instrument_name | year | month | instrument_type | expiry_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABAN10SEPFUT | ABAN | 10 | SEP | FUT | I |
| ABAN10OCTFUT | ABAN | 10 | OCT | FUT | II |
| ABAN10NOVFUT | ABAN | 10 | NOV | FUT | III |

My code look like
#1

```
def condition(x):
if x =='SEP':
    return "I"
elif x =='OCT':
    return "II"
elif x =='NOV':
    return "III"
else:
    return ''
```

#2

```
for index, row in path.iterrows():
    data = pd.read_parquet(row['location'])
    data['expiry_type'] = np.where((data['instrument_type'] == 'FUT'),data['month'].apply(condition),'')
```

Since I already know the unique values in month column so I created a custom function to replace values in expiry_type column. I have similar files like this so is there a way to find unique values and  replace automatically.
How do I do that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have grouped by `instrument_type`, you could build a function like the one in #1:

```py
def condition(x):
    if x.month =='SEP':
        return "I"
    elif x.month =='OCT':
        return "II"
    elif x.month =='NOV':
        return "III"
    else:
        return ''
```

And apply this function to the `expiry_type` column:

```py
df['expiry_type'] = df.apply(condition, axis = 1).
```

Comment: It seems like my question is unclear let me explain once again. If I group instrument_type ('FUT'), I will have three unique values like SEP,OCT and NOV in month column. Somehow I want to save these unique values and compare again with month column and replace values( 'I','II','III' ) in the expiry_type column. The thing is unique values in the month column will change every file which I'm iterating. So Instead of defining unique values in function I want to automate this process

Answer (score 0):

You can find the unique values in a column by using Pandas [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) function. Using a for loop for each DataFrame you have, apply the `unique` function over the `month` column to obtain a list of unique values. Then, create a dictionary using those values as keys and the new representation (roman numbers in this particular example) as values. You can then use the [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function to replace the values in the `month` column and assign the new ones to the `expiry_type` column.

```py
def toRoman(n):
    roman = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX', 'X', 'XI', 'XII']
    return roman[n]

df_list = ['df1.csv', 'df2.csv', 'df3.csv']
for df_file in df_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(df_file)
    g = df.groupby('instrument_type')
    uniq = g['month'].unique()[0]
    # create a dictionary using the unique values
    dict_map = {name:toRoman(idx) for idx,name in enumerate(uniq)}
    df['expiry_type'] = df['month'].map(dict_map)
```